# How to make a page keep loading a file (.txt) even its not there yet?

Tags: php, jquery, load, http-status-code-404

I want to load a txt file which is not there yet. I mean I'll get a pending status from server. And the page will only get respond 200 status from server when the txt file is there. Or there is no way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to code the server part, or the client part? Or both?

Comment: i want to code the client part...for it to wait until it gets the file...or should i change anything in web config? in order to give it more time before it execute the 404 error?

Comment: i just created my own php chat script...i've been playing around with PHP, Jquery, Javascript, just to send the strings to other page for few month already...now i know how web/browser chat can be posible...Thank You so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do{
$file = @file_get_contents("file.txt");
sleep(1);
}while(empty($file));
```

If we are talking about remote server, you should use cURL, and "load" file every couple of seconds, if string is empty, means there is no file.
This should be checked async.

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return curl_exec($ch);
}

do{
    $file = curl("http://example.com/file.txt");
    sleep(5);
}while(empty($file));
```

Comment: @webarto This doesn't seem to match the tags "php jquery load http-status-code-404 server-response". :)

Comment: @bzlm Yup, sorry, I added that :)

Comment: thanx guys for replying....havent really got myself into this community...makes me so happy!!!!

Comment: I would suggest something slightly different.  Do a `while(!file_exists($file)){sleep(1);} if(file_exists($file)){//process file, also deal with empty existing file with another while loop}`  This will tie up the script while the file doesn't exist with a while loop, then make sure it does exist afterwards and process it.  Suppressing errors with @ is a slow process, and if you're absolutely having to use it, it's not good programming.  If the file is already there then it would just skip the while loop.

Comment: I think it first checks if file exists before it tries to open it, but it is not local file that is in question here. If you have any other suggestion on how to check if remote file exists feel free to post.

Comment: @Phoenix this also works!! u guys really dropped me with some good solution...i used javascript to loop the settimeout but i crashed my browser with it! ;)

Comment: If you want to force a response after so much time without the text file being there, set a counter variable outside of the loop, and increment it in the loop and do something like `$i = 0;while(!file_exists($file)){sleep(1);if($i++ == 30){//handle no file;break;//or exit(); or die(); or whatever}}`

Comment: Yup, but the file is on remote server AFAIK.

Comment: @webarto what do mean by the file is on remote server AFAIK?

Comment: @skaloot Nothing, you should use database, not flat files for chat.

Comment: @webarto yeah i did...before this i store everything on Mysql n use javascript to loop the call every 1 second...so when they are more than 3 users, our (users) OS was hank, n my server was down..i even had an email from hosting company saying that they were to many traffic...hhahah...so do u have any other method? coz this one works quiet fine for me...  ;)

Comment: yo @Phoenix u helped a lot...here's are the result http://chat.skaloot-arts.com/ if u have time just go n have a look...thanx ya..

Comment: Ah, a chat application.  You know, there's another way you can do that too if you're interested in more advanced stuff.  Try setting up an IRC server and using sockets in PHP to connect to it.  You listen to the incoming pipe for messages and relay them to the client browser much like waiting for the file to show up and have contents, and put all the outgoing messages into the outbound pipe.

Comment: @Phoenix thanx but im not that good in server thingy...this simple chat app i build is good enough for now...by understanding the sleep function, i can now do a lot more....thanx bro...

Answer (score 2):

```
$.post("your/url", {}, function(file) {
    // since this is a success callback, once you are inside this block,
    // you got your file.
    // If you return anything other than 200 OK, this callback wouldn't get called
});
```